# trying to FTP a file with a special character

Tags: c#, ftp

I have the code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.UseBinary = true;   // Binary mode when downloading
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I always get the error: "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command".

The problem is the url contains a "#".  Since I can't stop people from creating that type of file, is there a way I can escape special characters and still process the file?

Comment: Can you provide a sample url?

Answer (score 7):

Do a string replace with `"#" ->"%23"`
URL encodings shouldn't contain a hash because:

> Some characters present the possibility of being misunderstood within URLs for various reasons. These characters should also always be encoded.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Bernard.  I feel better - it sounds like there is a solution.  Some folks asked for an example above, Just imagine the file name is "#test.txt".  Does anyone have a list of characters, I would need to escape?  thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm
 But you should look into the function posted by B Tyler, it's probably exactly what you want without worrying about which characters.

Comment: Where is the B Tyler Function?

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks to both of you.  I swear I didn't see that answer. :)

Comment: I want to note that since I had a Console App, I needed to change the "Target framework:" from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET framework 4".  This was the only way I could add System.Web to my references.  Once I got the function in scope, it worked great.  Thanks again to both B Tyler and Jean-Bernard Pellerin.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) to encode the special characters.